# Angular Apollo at the component / module level?

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

```
{
        provide: APOLLO_NAMED_OPTIONS,
        useFactory(httpLink: HttpLink): NamedOptions {
            return {
                default: {
                    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
                    link: split(
                        ({ query }) => {
                            // console.log(query);
                            const data = getMainDefinition(query);
                            console.log(data);
                            return (
                                data.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && data.operation === 'subscription'
                            );
                        },
                        httpLink.create({
                            uri: 'https://localhost:5001/graphql',
                        }),
                        new WebSocketLink({
                            uri: 'wss://localhost:5001/graphql',
                            options: {
                                lazy: true,
                                reconnect: true,
                            },
                        })
                    )
                },
            
                scanners: {
                    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
                    link: split(
                        ({ query }) => {
                            // console.log(query);
                            const data = getMainDefinition(query);
                            console.log(data);
                            return (
                                data.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && data.operation === 'subscription'
                            );
                        },
                        httpLink.create({
                            uri: 'https://localhost:5001/scanners',
                        }),
                        new WebSocketLink({
                            uri: 'wss://localhost:5001/scanners',
                            options: {
                                lazy: true,
                                reconnect: true,
                            },
                        })
                    )
                }
            }

        },
        deps: [HttpLink],
    },
```

We're currently using Angular Apollo like the above. The backend team wants to continue down this path and have separate paths for all major components. Ie: /scanners /users /dashboard, etc...

The way it's structured right now, all of my NamedOptions have to go into app.module - and this breaks our pattern of having all of our components / modules as npm packages that can be `npm install org-scanners` because the implementation team will still need to go into app.module and add the named option.

Is there any way to move the creation of the named option into the components module and inject that into app.module? Kinda like routes are handled?